# Are there any microbrewery in Lisbon/Tomar in portugal?

Tags: breweries, local

Are there any microbrewery in Lisbon/Tomar in Portugal?

What is the specialty brew in Portugal? Is there any special beer or beer-like alcohol from Portugal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oficina da Cerveja, shop

Sant’Ana LX Brewery, cerveja artisanal

Lisboa, rua Bernardim Ribeiro 53
oficina aberto ao público apenas Terças e Quintas das 14:30 às 19 h (sem necessitar de combinar antes) http://oficinadacerveja.pt/

The shop provides some products to home brewers.
The microbrewery (quite micro indeed) makes some really good brews in today’s IPA trend. During a stay with friends in september (Belgians), we bought some American Pale Ale (4,9 %) and some Rye IPA (6,8 %). Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

[Portugal Beer History](http://www.europeanbeerguide.net/portbrew.htm)

[Lisbon Beer Museum](http://www.portugaldailyview.com/whats-new/beer-paradise-lisbons-beer-museum)

Edit:  Dois Corvos and Oitava Colina are both craft breweries in the area.

Generally, Lisbon seems to be a wine destination, which means beer doesn't end up shining in any significant way in the region.

Comment: There are two craft breweries in Lisbon. The Lisbon Beer Museum (Museu da Cerveja) mostly has industrial beer and is mainly for tourists.

Answer (score 2):

The two craft breweries in Lisbon are Dois Corvos and Oitava Colina. Dois Corvos has a tasting room a couple km from the centre. Both make good beer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chain restaurant over in Portugal called [Cervejeira Lusitana](http://lusitana.com/); also known as the Lusitanian Brewery. This restaurant is a brewpub that sells beer and Portuguese food. There should be a few in Lisbon, but I am not quite sure about Tomar.

Portugal is not really known for their beer that I know of. It seems like the beers they sell commonly aren't too much on the hoppy-side either. From what I found about the usual style of beer over there, it seems that lagers are very common. There are a few other styles it seems, but no real specialty brew. I would ask around and see if any of the locals know of any particular bars and brews to try.

EDIT: Forgot to add the [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g189158-d1049980-Reviews-Cervejeira_Lusitana-Lisbon_Estremadura.html) link for them.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.ratebeer.com/search.php and in the Brewer Search enter Lisbon in the City and Portugal in the Country, then click Search.

It returns 4 breweries.

- 100 Maneiras Rua do Teixeira, 35 Lisbon      Portugal
- Amnesia Brewery Oeiras, Lisbon       Portugal
- Cerveja Aroeira Lisbon       Portugal
- Dois Corvos Cervejeira Lisbon        Portugal

Answer (score 1):

Almost five years after this question was asked I can add **Quimera Brewpub**, in Rua Prior do Crato, Lisbon, that I visited in March 2019. The About page of [their website](http://www.quimerabrewpub.com/) states:

> We have 12 taps of craft beers and bottles, all produced either by us or from good Portuguese micro breweries.